# getResourceAsStream() doesn't work on ubuntu, works on windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, resources

I have the following code snippet:

```
String name = "_a.properties"
InputStream in  = PropertyResolver.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name);
String name2 = "folder/_b.properties"
InputStream in2  = PropertyResolver.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name2);
```

This is a java/spring boot/maven project, directory structure is shown as follows:

```
/config
  _a.properties
  /folder
    _b.properties
```

On Windows 10 64bit (Java version 1.8.0_151) machine running java -jar (myfile) both of the inputstreams resolve successfully.

Running on Ubuntu 64bit (openjdk version 10.0.1) the second one resolves, while the first one is always null.

I have tried changing the values of name to "/_a.properties", and "./_a.properties" but nothing seems to work.

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: What is your error? IOException? Is your code running from the same relative directory in both cases?

Comment: How about String name2 = "./folder/_b.properties" ?

Comment: there is no error or exception thrown, the inputstream is simply null.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the question. The second example resolves in windows and ubuntu, the first one only resolves on windows. I have tried your suggestion Quang and it did not work, I also have tried using Oracle JDK 1.8 and the issue persists.